# How to Findcontrol when we use literal to create it

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

I am using a panel and then I create a literal in it, than I create :

```
string temp ="
<input type="checkbox" id="forum0">
<input type="checkbox" id="forum1">
<input type="checkbox" id="forum2">
<input type="checkbox" id="forum3">
<input type="checkbox" id="forum4">
<input type="checkbox" id="forum5">
" ...
```

and then assign this sting to

```
literal.text=temp;
```

now if i want to find the checkbox with id=forum0  ho do i do that i am using findcontrol i have used almost everything kindly help with example.

thank you

Comment: @user479301 -  Find the checkbox and then what? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding form elements to your form by using literal controls, you can't get these controls by FindControl method. Because they're added to your page as static html elements.

You have two options to reach them at server side :

1. You should add them as server control. Then you can perfectly access them.
2. If you only want to access their values when your page posts back, you can use Request :

   string yourControlsValue = Request["Your_Controls_Name"];

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net will only instantiate control objects for the controls found on the aspx page, not that are delivered through the actual rendered HTML, which is where your checkbox is being created. You should find a parameter being returned to the Page handler with the name 'forum0' and that should be accessible through the `Request["forum0"]` construct.